# Should i make a seperate app to send push notifications to 40-50k users in RoR App or use background jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, sidekiq

I have a rails application that is in fact a backend of a popular IOS application which have a user base of **200k users** who needs to be notified time to time.

Daily **40-50k users** will be notified using push notifications. These push notifications will be **realtime** and **scheduled** ones. eg: if a new users signs up he will be notified within few seconds. eg: scheduled notifications will run at 10 pm daily with limited users ranging 10k-30k or sometimes more upto 100k.

I also will be doing business reporting to generate list of users fulfilling certain criteria and it requires firing mysql queries that could take upto 1-2 minutes of time.

My area of concern is **should i have a seperate application with seperate mirror db** to send push notifications to these users so my IOS users doesnt feel lag while using this application when push notifications are triggered or business reporting query is triggered.

Or  **should i use background jobs** like **Rails Active job, Sidekiq or Sucker Punch** to perform push notifications and triggering business reporting queries.

Is background jobs in rails so powerful that it can manage this condition and doesn't let App users to feel lag in experience.

My application stack is:

```
Rails: 4.1.6
Ruby: 2.2
DB: Mysql
PaaS: AWS Elastic Beans
IOS Push gem: Houston
```

Comment: Consider carefully the case if the app doubles or triples in users.

Comment: could happen in couple of years in that case what do you suggest?

Comment: Sounds like you need a system architect to come up with a long-term product technology plan which considers a matrix of variables and outcomes with associated probabilities, and costs. If you're a developer on a project, I wouldn't think this type of strategic business decision should be placed on you.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, there are several factors that affect my decision.

### 1. Does your service need to keep many persistent connections?

If your answer is YES, then use another language which has better asynchronous IO (like Node.js) to implement your push service.

If your answer is NO, which means you only send requests to third-party services (like APNS), then consider the next factor.

### 2. Do you have to reuse your domain model in your push service?

If your answer is YES, then stick to Active Job + Sidekiq.

If your answer is NO, which means you only uses some fields (like `id`, `name`) of some table (like `users`), then consider the next factor.

### 3. Does your server have a limited memory resource?

A rails processes often consumes several hundreds of MB of memory, and Sidekiq requires a separate Rails process which can't be preforked (which means it does not share memory with your Rails app).

So if your answer is YES, then consider create a separate lightweight push service.

As for mirror database, if I have to do heavy query before push, I will definitely use mirror database.